# near login command failed to verify accountId. [-32700] Parse error: Failed parsing args: missing field 'account_id'

Tags: near

When I tried to use near CLI command near login. I got the following msg (showing in the attached picture) before I can approve access from wallet.testnet.near.org

[near login failed msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjkSK.jpg)

Comment: I'm getting the same sort of error. I've deleted my browser local storage, deleted the `.near-credentials` files, re-installed `near-cli` and tried to generate my own key locally to no avail. I have others on my team that had no problem, though, using this link: https://www.near-sdk.io/zero-to-hero/basics/set-up-skeleton

Answer (score 2):

I looked into the near-cli source code and found that there was a [callback using port 5000](https://github.com/near/near-cli/blob/2c21e2e2a80bff4506362f82b705bdc4de4639a4/index.js#L131). My Mac (Monterey 12.3.1) was using port 5000 already, which I couldn't kill off and which in turn led me to a quick Google search. All the articles basically say this:
[image: Turn off AirPlay Reciever]
Did so, and now I'm able to use `near login` successfully.